# Form data and file does not upload to Google spreadsheet?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, file-upload, google-sheets, spreadsheet

The below code had worked for the first 4 input fields and also upload files to the spreadsheet. For the first time, it uploaded data and file to the spreadsheet but when I added more input fields into the form I also customized the **code.gs** but it does not work. when I submit it stay in uploading state and do not sends data to the spreadsheet.

**code.gs**

```
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms.html').setTitle("Registration With Document");
}
function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, code, issues, item, description, problem, defect, 
solution, notes) {
try {
var dropbox = "Received Files";
var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1xqpdunLg-ygxOxwJvEHjScNhIT2qVgsF');
var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
    bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
    blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
    file = folder.createFolder([name, email].join(" ")).createFile(blob),
    filelink=file.getUrl() ;
var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
lock.waitLock(30000);  
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Diy70efaCR8Po5drNNZ5_AcJ_nQEJP37_CMSLXlxLQs");
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
var headRow =  1;
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
var row = [];
for (i in headers){
  if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
    row.push(new Date());
  } else if (headers[i] == "code"){
    row.push(code);
  } else if (headers[i] == "issues"){
    row.push(issues);
  } else if (headers[i] == "item"){
    row.push(item);
  } else if (headers[i] == "description"){
    row.push(description);
  } else if (headers[i] == "problem"){
    row.push(problem);
  } else if (headers[i] == "defect"){
    row.push(defect);
  } else if (headers[i] == "solution"){
    row.push(solution);
  } else if (headers[i] == "notes"){
    row.push(notes);
  } else if (headers[i] == "filelink"){
    row.push(filelink);
} 
}
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
return "OK";
} catch (f) {
return f.toString();
} finally { //release lock
lock.releaseLock();
}
}
function setup() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("1Diy70efaCR8Po5drNNZ5_AcJ_nQEJP37_CMSLXlxLQs", doc.getId());
}
```

**forms.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_blank">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Registration</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
<style>
.disclaimer{width: 480px; color:#646464;margin:20px auto;padding:0 16px;text-align:center;font:400 
12px Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif}.disclaimer a{color:#009688}#credit{display:none}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="main" id="form" novalidate="novalidate" style="max-width: 480px;margin: 40px auto;">
<div id="forminner">
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12
<h5 class="center-align teal-text">Repair/Issue Form</h5>
<p class="disclaimer">Fill up all fields.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="code" type="text" name="Date Code" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
<label for="code">Date Code</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="issues" type="text" name="Reported Issues" class="validate" required="" aria- 
required="true">
<label for="issues">Reported Issues</label>
</div>
</div>      
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="item" type="text" name="Item Number" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
<label for="item">Item Number</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="description" type="text" name="Description" class="validate" required="" aria- 
required="true">
<label for="description">Description</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="problem" type="text" name="Problem" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
<label for="problem">Problem</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="defect" type="text" name="Frequency of Defect" class="validate" required="" aria- 
required="true">
<label for="defect">Frequency of Defect</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="solution" type="text" name="Possible Issues" class="validate" required="" aria- 
required="true">
<label for="solution">Possible Issues</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="notes" type="text" name="Notes" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
<label for="notes">Notes</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="file-field input-field col s12">
<div class="btn">
<span>File</span>
<input id="files" type="file">
</div>
<div class="file-path-wrapper">
<input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Select a file on your computer">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s6">
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="submitForm(); return 
false;">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12" id = "progress">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="success" style="display:none">
<h5 class="left-align teal-text">File Uploaded</h5>
<p>Your file has been successfully uploaded.</p>
<p class="center-align"><a  class="btn btn-large" onclick="restartForm()" >Restart</a></p>
</div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
var file, reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
if (e.target.error != null) {
howError("File " + file.name + " could not be read.");
return;
} else {
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
.uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result, file.name, $('input#code').val(),
$('input#issues').val(), $('input#item').val(), $('input#description').val()),
$('input#problem').val(), $('input#defect').val(), $('input#solution').val(), 
$('input#notes').val();
}
};
function showSuccess(e) {
if (e === "OK") {
$('#forminner').hide();
$('#success').show();
} else {
showError(e);
}
}

function restartForm() {
$('#form').trigger("reset");
$('#forminner').show();
$('#success').hide();
$('#progress').html("");
}
function submitForm() {
var files = $('#files')[0].files;
if (files.length === 0) {
showError("Please select a file to upload");
return;
}
file = files[0];
if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
showError("The file size should be < 5 MB. ");
return;
}

showMessage("Uploading file..");
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
function showError(e) {
$('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
}
function showMessage(e) {
$('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').material_select();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's an example of a form that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59379764/7215091

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what issue you're having? Maybe provide a simplified example? Please consider that just posting hundreds of lines of code without proper indentation is not the best way to get help from this community. Also, a copy of the spreadsheet free of sensitive information might be useful. Finally, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, sir When I submitted the form, it got stuck on "Uploading file..." and I got an error in the console that "google is not defined" on "index.html:134".

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at the rest of the code but there is a misplaced parenthesis

change for that :

```
{
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
.uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result, file.name, $('input#code').val(),
$('input#issues').val(), $('input#item').val(), $('input#description').val(),
$('input#problem').val(), $('input#defect').val(), $('input#solution').val(), 
$('input#notes').val());
}
```

Comment: I had tested including this parenthesis, It doesn't work actually I had added the parenthesis after a description you can see it but the issue is same with both cases